# stripe.com node.js code receives no webhook

Tags: node.js, stripe-payments

In my accountSettings > webhooks I have:

- url = http://example.com/stripe
- Mode = test
- Send me all events = ✔

But my node.js code receives no webhooks:

```
var stripe=require('stripe')('sk_test_myapikey');
var express=require('express');
var bodyParser=require('express/node_modules/body-parser');
var app=require('express')();
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended:false}));
app.post('/stripe',function(request,response){//never fires
        console.log('hello?');
        console.log(request.body);
        response.send(200);
        });
app.listen(8080);
```

I have no examples to go by that aren't old apart from this in the official stripe docs:

```
var stripe = require("stripe")("sk_test_myapikey");

// Using Express
app.post("/my/webhook/url", function(request, response) {
  // Retrieve the request's body and parse it as JSON
  var event_json = JSON.parse(request.body);

  // Do something with event_json

  response.send(200);
});
```

### the checkout page is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.js"></script>
        <script src="https://checkout.stripe.com/checkout.js"></script>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Stripe</title>
    </head>
    <body style="background:#41ACE6;">
        <div style="background:url('logo.stripe.png');background-position:center center;background-size:50%;background-repeat:no-repeat;position:fixed;left:0px;right:0px;top:0px;bottom:0px;"></div>
        <script>
            var handler=StripeCheckout.configure({
                key:'pk_test_myapikey'
            ,   image:'icon.png'
            ,   locale:'auto'
            ,   token:function(token){
                    handler.close();
                    console.log(token);
                    var vals=
                     '<input type="hidden" name="token" value="'+token.id+'"/>'
                    +'<input type="hidden" name="used" value="'+token.used+'"/>'
                    +'<input type="hidden" name="provider" value="'+'<?php echo $_POST["provider"];?>'+'"/>'
                    +'<input type="hidden" name="account_id" value="'+'<?php echo $_POST["account_id"];?>'+'"/>'
                    +'<input type="hidden" name="quantity" value="'+'<?php echo $_POST["quantity"];?>'+'"/>'
                    ;
                    $('<form style="display:hidden" action="http://example.com/result.php" method="POST">'+vals+'</form>').submit();
                    }});
            handler.open({
                name:'example'
            ,   description:'description'
            ,   currency:"usd"
            ,   amount:<?php echo ((int)$_POST["quantity"])*100;?>
                });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Sounds like a problem with stripe, assuming your network is allowing stripe access to your server.

Comment: good points, I have sent them an email about it... but the problem could still be mine! I will paste the official response / fix here regardless as I've got to make this work and good future reference for me and others.

Comment: Thinking about it a staff member from stripe was able to send me a test webhook late last night so. That counts out my network not allowing access

Comment: Is this an account webhook or a connect webhook?

Comment: If you go to your stripe dashboard and go to events and webhooks, does the webhook history show events as being sent?

Comment: dashboard > events and webhooks shows no USD webhooks , with exception a few early tests of bitcoin webhooks that I can see and one event where I created a product.

Comment: @BenMuircroft Hey having the exact same issue. req.body is empty, but webhook seems to be working fine. Did you figure this out? any help appreciated thanks.